# Android: Intent and exchanging data between components

Tags: java, android, android-intent, ipc

I read about Interprocess Communication (IPC) and creating send data from one component to another component.
What I knew is that IPC defines the communication channel between the different components.
The channel will have programming interfaces for the components to send data through. Ways to create an interface are such as AIDL, Binder, and Messenger.
After creating the interface, data to be sent over it must be **Parcel**.
So the summary steps are as follows:
 1. Create a programming interface.
 2. Bind the interface to an application component.
 3. Components sending data to that component must convert data into Parcel.

But suddenly found what is called **Intent** that can send data from one component to another without this overhead.
I need explanation about how Intent can send data without having an interface to be created?
Is intent internally have an interface?
What is the relation between intent and IPC, bound service, and interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow you have a lot of confusion here.  Let's see if I can clear things up.

1)IPC does not send data from one component to another (it can, but its an inefficient way to do that).  IPC sends data from one process to another.  An Android app is generally one process, although it doesn't have to be (services are sometimes placed into another process by the developer).  The reason this is an important difference is that processes cannot share memory, so special methods like IPC are needed to send any data between them.

2)Data sent between components do not have to be a Parcel.  That's one way, and its the way Android uses when sending startup parameters around.  But it's not necessary.

3)Using a Binder to talk to a service is only possible if the two are in the same process.  Its a method to totally avoid using IPC.

4)AIDL is a wrapper around an IPC method.  AIDL uses IPC, it just tries to make it look like normal function calls to the client.

5)An Intent object is an abstraction for all the data needed to start a service or activity in Android.  It will include parameters, which may or may not be in Parcels.  It may or may not use IPC to send those parameters (if the target Activitiy or Service is in another APK it will.  If it isn't it may not).

I think the problem here is you don't really understand what a process is, what an Android component is, and how processes actually communicate.  I suggest doing some studying up on that.

Comment: So we can say that is to communicate between two activities in the same process Binder is used and Intent is an implementation Android provide for the Binder?